# Realm and Diffable Data Source

Tags: ios, swift

Has anyone tried to use Realm in conjunction with diffable data sources? There seems to be an issue I can't get my head around.

So, when when we use the "traditional" data source API, in **cellForRowAt** we get the object for a particular row on an *index-based* basis and since Realm returns objects inside its generic **Results** type (e.g. `let items = Results<Item>`), which conforms to Collection, we can basically access the element like always: `items[indexPath.row]`

However, when you use **diffable data source** and create a *snapshot*, you have it like this: `var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Int, Item>`. You add a section by doing `snapshot.appendSections([0])` and then you have to add items to that section. **My main issue here** is that you can't do `snapshot.appendItems(items)` since `items` is of type `Results<Item>`, not `Array<Item>`. Am I missing something here?

Also, Realm's `Object` class seems to have its own implementation of `Hashable` so I think there's no way of ensuring the uniqueness of objects apart from overriding Realm's `primaryKey` and implementing your own auto increment feature. All that seems a bit weird to me to the point where I'm thinking to switch to Core Data.

Haven't found similar topics on StackOverflow so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Has anyone found a way to do this without converting to Array (as mentioned in all answers, which loads all objects in memory and defeats the basic purpose of lazy loading!) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can covert `Result<Items>` to `Array` using an extension:

```
extension Results {
  func toArray() -> [Element] {
    return compactMap {
        $0
    }
  }
}
```

You can use it like: `results.toArray()` and it will give you the array and then with your case you can `append` data into it.

Comment: Realm Database defers execution of a query until you access the results, so as soon as you convert the results into an Array it executes the query. If you have a query with thousands of results, this will impact performance. Ideally you would pass the query to the datasource and let the cell/tableview only query the cells it needs instead of all of them.

Comment: How to do this with lazy loading?

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can simply use this method :

```
let realmArray = Array(items!)
```

Comment: Thank you, Roma!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use map() to transform an array

```
items = realm.objects(Item.self).map({ $0 })
```

Comment: you have not asked a question or specify what help you need. Provide more information to help others answer the question.

Comment: I wanted to answer the question above, what I wrote is the answer. This is another way to do so.